# How to make my telegram bot's handler not block each other?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a bot made with `python-telegram-bot` library. Here, I have to pass `block=False` to make the functions not block each other. But as my code gets bigger, adding `block=True` to each handler becomes quite a hassle. Is there a way to make all the handlers `block=False`?

Here's how my code looks like now.

```py
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, CallbackContext, Defaults
from telegram import Update, Bot, constants


async def start_c(u: Update, c: CallbackContext):
    bot: Bot = c.bot
    chat_id = u.message.chat_id
    await bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "<b>I'm alive!</b>")


async def help_c(u: Update, c: CallbackContext):
    bot: Bot = c.bot
    chat_id = u.message.chat_id
    await bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Help Command!")


def main():
    key = "MY TOKEN"
    df = Defaults(parse_mode=constants.ParseMode.HTML)
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token(key).connect_timeout(30).defaults(df).build()

    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_c, block=False))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_c, block=False))

    app.run_polling()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried storing the **commandNames** and **functions** in a *dict* and then iterate over them and add `block=False` to each one. But that's a bit of code too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `block=False` in the `Defaults` along with `parse_mode=constants.ParseMode.HTML`.
Check out the docs for [Defaults](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.5/telegram.ext.defaults.html#defaults) to see what else you can pass there.

Here's how you can use it:

```py
from telegram.ext import Defaults # import the Defaults class

# Your Other Code Here

def main():
    key = "MY TOKEN"
    df = Defaults(block=False) # `block=True` for all handlers
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token(key).connect_timeout(30).defaults(df).build()

    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_c)) # No need to set here anymore.
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_c, block=True)) # but you can manually set it to `True` for some handlers

    app.run_polling()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```